# Cannot retrieve a array of string from web service

Tags: c#, web-services

```
public ArrayList myFunc(string arg1, string arg2)
```

I have tested that web method on browser and it works fine.
In the client, I retrieve return value from myFunc by doing this:

```
string[] ret = ws.myFunc("arg1", "arg2");
```

Problem is ret always contains nothing although when test on browser i received this

```
<ArrayOfAnyType xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"                xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">str01</anyType>
    <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">str02</anyType>
</ArrayOfAnyType>
```

Am I missing some thing? Thanks you!

Comment: what is the myFunc signature in the proxy class generated by your designer when you added the web reference? I don't think you can treat ArrayList as string array... you need to confirm to the method signature in the proxy class..

Comment: it is    string[] myFunc(string arg1, string arg2)

Comment: did you check the length of the array after calling the web method? does it return anything?

Comment: its length = 0. When i change the signature of web method to return string[], it works fine. So the problem may be by casting ArrayList to string[] on web service.

Comment: since it is complex type, you need to serialize it...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried -

```
List<string> ret = ws.myFunc("arg1", "arg2");
```

As the return from the web service may be in the form of `ArrayOfString`.